# Slow speed with shared folders in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-shares

I'm using VirtualBox 3 on my Ubuntu 9.04 desktop, and I've got a VM with Windows XP sp3 mapping my ~/Documents folder as a shared folder. The virtualised Windows is mapping My Documents to the shared folder directly (//vboxsvr/Documents).

The problem is that every time that I'm interacting with the shared folder (i.e.: access, list files, etc.) it takes several seconds to do so.

Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: I have the exact same problem with an XP Host and both an Ubuntu guest and XP guest. Must be a VirtualBox thing (versus an O/S thing). I'd be interested in seeing a solution.

Comment: I think it is only slow in listing. Writing and reading are not slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with name resolution.  That happens on Windows machines while it tries to use the virtual network adapter to resolve the name.  I have resolved this issue on a Windows host, but not on an Ubuntu host.

I found [this site](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=13129&p=54184&hilit=%2Fetc%2Fhosts#p54184) that has some suggestions:

> In `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`  change the line
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1       localhost
> ```
>
> by appending `Vboxsvr` and your computer name
>   so for a computer named `the_box` it would become
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1       localhost Vboxsvr the_box
> ```

Comment: Already saw the linked-to site but it did not help me... editing `\etc\hosts` has no effect on speed, and anyway my share is already mounted as a drive letter, but access to it is still far slower than local disk. 4.1.2 guest additions.

Comment: My understanding was that the hosts file fix was only for Windows guests (in fact the hosts file has to be changed in the guest, not the host) since their shares are mounted as network drives.

Comment: Yes that is what I did, edited the abovementioned file in the Windows guest. Also edited `lmhosts` to include `255.255.255.255        VBOXSVR #PRE
255.255.255.255        VBOXSRV #PRE` as I have seen in official VirtualBox  documentation. Performance still very poor when using the shared folder in a Windows 10 guest on Ubuntu host (operations using the guest’s native disk are fine).

Comment: See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch12.html#idm11324 by the way.